# Javascript : Jump to method definition using eclipse

Tags: java, javascript, eclipse

In eclipse for java we have a feature to navigate to the method definition by "holding the CTRL key and move mouse cursor over the method name. Method name will become a hyper link. Simply click it to go to the method definition."

But we don't have a similar feature for jquery or backbone in eclipse.

Is there any plugin available for this feature.
Does anyone have any idea about this??

Comment: @VahanVardanyan could you please elaborate it more.

Answer (score 0):

using shift+F3 takes you to the definition after placing the cursor on name

Comment: Go to Windows->Preferences->keys->choose scheme as default.
Then try pressing F3 after placing the cursor on name.

Comment: this didn't work for me :/ 
any other ideas please?